# Error at define new function in mysql error #1064

Tags: mysql, sql, function

I am trying to define the following function in mysql but I get an error:

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE FUNCTION salario_maximo(dep INT) 
RETURNS FLOAT
BEGIN
    DECLARE msalario FLOAT;
    DECLARE dpto INT;
    SELECT COUNT(*) INTO dpto FROM departamentos WHERE DEPT_NO=dep;
    IF(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM departamentos WHERE DEPT_NO=dep>0)
    BEGIN
        IF(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM empleados WHERE DEPT_NO=dep>0)
        BEGIN
            SELECT max(salario) INTO msalario from empleados where dept_no=dep;
        END
        ELSE
        BEGIN
            SET msalario = 0;
        END
    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN
        SET msalario = -1;
    END
    RETURN msalario;
END; // 
DELIMITER ;
```

My error is:

> #1064 - Algo está equivocado en su sintax cerca 'BEGIN
> IF(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM empleados WHERE DEPT_NO=dep>0)
> ' en la linea 8

I need some help! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are couple of things here.

First, you need a "THEN" after a if condition.

Second, you need to close your IF ELSE block with a END IF statement.

Also, put a semicolon after the END statements.

Try this:

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE FUNCTION salario_maximo(dep INT) 
RETURNS FLOAT
BEGIN
    DECLARE msalario FLOAT;
    DECLARE dpto INT;
    SELECT COUNT(*) INTO dpto FROM departamentos WHERE DEPT_NO=dep;
    IF(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM departamentos WHERE DEPT_NO=dep>0)
    THEN
        BEGIN
            IF(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM empleados WHERE DEPT_NO=dep>0)
            THEN
            BEGIN
                SELECT max(salario) INTO msalario from empleados where dept_no=dep;
            END;
            ELSE
            BEGIN
                SET msalario = 0;
            END;
            END IF;
        END;
    ELSE
    BEGIN
        SET msalario = -1;
    END;
    END IF;
    RETURN msalario;
END; // 
DELIMITER ;
```